# Concatenate a special character to a column of data?

Tags: excel, list, concatenation

```
9
37
92
93
96
98
118
128
135
136
139
```

I have about 13K plus records like the list above. And I want to append a ',' after every number?

What would be the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: the numbers are arranged in a column.

Comment: What does that comment mean? Why don't you just fix the question to show how the data is actually arranged?

Comment: What language do you want to do this in?

Comment: The data is in an column in excel :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)!

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and choose the *Replace* tab, then fill in these details:

**Find what**: `\r\n`

**Replace with**: `,\r\n`

**Search mode**: Extended

Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>, and Bob's your uncle!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your os and language:

1. Read a linw
2. Write all but the carriage return
3. Write ,
4. Write the carriage return
5. carry on at 1. unless you have finished.

On Unix/Linux boxes you could use sed or awk, just about any programming language, I wouldn't recommend asm or fortran but not impossible with them.
On any machine any language available that supports text processing, any utility that supports regular expressions.  In excel you can create another column that concatenated the contents of the cell to the left and ',' then hide the original column

Answer (score 0):

for data in column  A1 you can use below

```
CONCAT(A1,CHAR(39), char(44),CHAR(39))
```

FYI,

CHAR(39)  - '

CHAR(44) - ,